# Java mission control - visualize event

Tags: java, jmc, java-mission-control

Is it possible to visualize JFR events on chart? Sure I can browse them in log section but I'd like to visiualize them on chart also.

A good example would be "Machine total" attribute from "CPU Load" event.

If it is possible how to achieve it?

Comment: Of course you can.

Comment: So what is your question? How to get other people to do your work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Designer View:

- Window -> Show View -> Designer (Unsupported)
- Open a JFR file
- Go to the appropriate tab
- Click the red stop button in the designer view
- Use context menus in either the editor view or designer view to modify the existing GUI
- Use the designer view and New Group or New tab to add new GUI (close and reopen the JFR file to view the new tab structure)

This is both unsupported and undocumented, but is however how the standard JFR GUI is built. I'm trying to find an online video where either I or someone else has demoed this..

(Your example with "Machine total" is already visualized though, both on General/Overview and Threads/Overview)

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot! Did not know about this feature. General tab contains "Machine Total" in terms of CPU not load which are two completly differnet values.

Comment: Found a video where this is demoed by my colleague Marcus Hirt - https://vimeo.com/98922031, starts at 40:50 into the video.